# swing: appropriate Listener for JTextField change events

Tags: swing, listener, jtextfield

Which type of Listener do I use for listening to changed text events in a [JTextField](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)? (I should know this or be able to tell from the Javadoc but I can't seem to figure it out.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the underlying document:

```
myTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener();
```