# Let ActionListener listen for change in JTextField instead of only enter?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

So as you may know, if you have a text field and you add an ActionListener to it, it will only listen to the keypress of the enter button. However, I want to let my ActionListener listen to changes in text of the . So basically I've got this:

```
    public static JPanel mainPanel() { 
    JPanel mainp = new JPanel(); 
    JTextArea areap = new JTextArea("Some text in the textarea"); 
    JTextField fieldp = new JTextField("Edit this"); 
    areap.setEditable(false); 
    fieldp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if(//change in textfield, for instance a letterpress or space bar)
                   { 
                        //Do this
                   } 
        }
    });
    mainp.add(areap);
    mainp.add(fieldp); 
    return mainp;
}
```

Any way I can listen to changes in text (like documented in the actionPerformed event)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [swing: appropriate Listener for JTextField change events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165071/swing-appropriate-listener-for-jtextfield-change-events)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From an answer by [@JRL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35501/jrl)

---

Use the underlying document:

```
myTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener();
```

Comment: What about PropertyChangeEvent?

Answer (score 0):

Documents are the mechanisms java swing uses to store the text inside of a JTextField.  DocumentListeners are objects that implement the DocumentListener interface and thus make it possible for you to list to changes in the document, i.e. changes in the text of the JTextField.

To use the document and documentlistener capabilities, as suggested above extend your class (probably but not necessarily a JFrame) so that it implements the DocumentListener interface.  Implement all the methods for the interface (most likely your java ide can do that semi-automatically for you.  FYI, the DocumentListener interface has three methods, one for inserting characters (into the text field), one for removing characters, and one for changing attributes.  You are going to want to implement the first two as they are called when characters are added (the first one) or deleted (the second one).  To get the changed text, you can either ask the document for the text, or more simply call myTextField.getText().

C'est tout!

Phil Troy