# searching but did not need a button, JFrame

Tags: java, database, swing, autocomplete, jframe

I have a JFrame which there is a table and a search has been connected to a database.
I want to search but to do so does not require a button. So, the search will be done right when I started to fill the name in textfield.
Like ajax in html.
Can this be done in java???

Comment: I think you looking for something like [this](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/swing/autosuggest.html)

Comment: *"I want to search.."* Search what?  The data currently in the table or the DB itself?

Comment: i want to search data in database and display it to the Jtable, So, the search will be done right when I started to fill the name in textfield.

Comment: I think you might be in need of a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html), each time a charcter is inserted, removed or changed Document Listener events will be fired, in those events simply search for the text and display the results, thus as the user types/removes characters again newer results will be displayed

Answer (score 3):

> So, the search will be done right when I started to fill the name in textfield

You can react on all of the input by attaching a `DocumentListener` to the `Document` of the `JTextField`. That listener will be informed each time the user provides input to the text field (whether it is trough typing, drag-and-drop, copy-paste, ... ).

The catch however is what you want to do on the user input. The `DocumentListener` is triggered on the Event Dispatch Thread and this thread should not be blocked by long running operations or your UI will freeze. Performing a database query is considered a 'long running operation'. This means you will have to make sure your search is executed on a background thread. Once the search is complete, you can update the table, which must be done on the Event Dispatch Thread. The `SwingWorker` class can be useful in this situation. More information on the threading rules can be found in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

The second catch is that you probably want to cancel the previous search when new input is provided. Most likely a user can type faster then you can query a database and populate a `JTable` with the results (assuming the network connection is not that fast).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done in Java using an actionListener attached to the textfield. See here for [actionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) javadocs.

There is a similar stackoverflow question here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383975/let-actionlistener-listen-for-change-in-jtextfield-instead-of-only-enter)

Comment: i think too that this question is about autocomplete / decorator