# Make input field auto format number with dot separator using JTextfield in Java (Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, addition, separator

i'm newbie in Java
In my first Java program (using Netbeans) i want to add input field auto format number with dot "." separator using JTextfield.
Here is my short code :

```
private void PayTransKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
// TODO add your handling code here:
String b;
b = PayTrans.getText();
if (b.isEmpty()){
    b = "0";
}
else {
    b = b.replace(".","");
    b = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).format(Double.parseDouble(b));
    b = b.replace(",", ".");
}
PayTrans.setText(b);
}
```

But I feel less than perfect, because the caret/cursor can't move by arrow key in the keyboard. I try to search better code but I've never find it. Did anyone have the solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) instead.

```
private DecimalFormatSymbols dfs;
private DecimalFormat dFormat;

dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.'); //separator for the decimals
dfs.setGroupingSeparator(','); //separator for the thousands
dFormat = new DecimalFormat ("#0.##", dfs);

JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(dFormat);
```

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) a link about customizing the format.

Comment: Thanks, Good idea. But the results are not directly view in JFormattedTextField when I type a thousands number. The result are newly view after I move the focus to other object.

Comment: This is how JFormattedTextField works. May you could check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383975/let-actionlistener-listen-for-change-in-jtextfield-instead-of-only-enter

Answer (score 1):

Change the locale.

In `ENGLISH` the thousands separator `,` and the decimal separator is `.`. In a continental language, like `FRENCH`, this is the other way around.

You can also parse numbers in a locale aware way with a `NumberFormat`. You shouldn't need to do any replacing.

Comment: Thanks, i was change to GERMAN.