# How can I print the text I typed in my first class to my second class?

Tags: java, swing, class, actionlistener, jtextfield

Someone please help me? How can I print the text I typed in the textfield into another class? Is thing has something to do with get and set text? This is my first class

```
public class Name extends JFrame {

JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JLabel yourname = new JLabel("Name");
JTextField text = new JTextField(30);


public Name(){

    add(yourname);
    add(text);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(900,600);

}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Name go = new Name();
   go.setVisible(true);
   go.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   go.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}}
```

And this is my second class

```
public class Output extends JFrame {
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();

Output(){

    add(yourname); 


}

public static void main(String args[]){

    Output receipt = new Output ();
    receipt.setVisible(true);


}}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to **listen** to changes on the `JTextField`.

Something like:

```
public class ListenerForTextField extends JFrame {
  JTextField text = new JTextField("Some Value");

  public ListenerForTextField () {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    text.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //SomeOtherClass a = new SomeOtherClass();
        //a.useText(text.getText());
      }
    });
}
```

- See this tutorial for more help: [ActionListener On JTextField](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/AddactionlistenertoJTextField.htm).
- And this, also: [Learn From Mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383975/let-actionlistener-listen-for-change-in-jtextfield-instead-of-only-enter).

Comment: @Charity Rama - If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. Welcome to Stack Overflow!